# Unable to execute PHP action via Postman

Tags: php, web-scraping, postman

I am trying to write code to download files from a financial data website. The file is accessible and easily downloadable by clicking the page, but my goal is to be able to reach the file via a POST request, with what I could deduce from Chrome's inspector.

My request never seems to reach the downloadable zip file, I'm not certain how it is wrong, I probably missed something reading the html.

[This is the page](http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/ascii/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2000)

This is the request I'm sending through Postman (POST):

```
http://www.histdata.com/get.php?tk=216a804365eccace285d20afed7acefe&date=2000&datemonth=2000&platform=ASCII&timeframe=M1&fxpair=EURUSD
```

Comment: POST or GET?... pick one....

Comment: POST, absolutely. What's misleading is that the form executes the action /get.php

Answer (score 1):

POST is not going to work on a get.php url.

use something like CURL to read the file from an external web.